# cobalt can't render "awebp.html" properly

Tags: cobalt

as previous question, you tell us we can test the pre-certification by https://qual-e.appspot.com/awebp.html.
currently we can see the scrolling issue you had specified.
we also see another issue that focused GIF item will render nothing,white picture only.
 
is it correct? or have next release?

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt does not support GIF decoding, and there are no scheduled plans to support it.

Comment: Yes, ignore that animated GIF display issue on Cobalt. It was added just for a comparison and shows the expected animation.